# Reference as return type

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm having trouble understanding why and how the following functions work:

```
personType& setLastName(string last);
personType& setFirstName(string first);
```

This is the solution in the book Data Structures Using C++ by D.S.Malik. Using these functions, the output is "Brad Pitt", which is correct. However, the explanation does not satisfy me at all. Can you explain why and how this works?

I tried to understand it on my own for a while. This is what I did. I changed the functions as following, and kept the main.cpp the same

```
personType setLastName(string last) { lastName=last; return *this; }
personType setFirstName(string first); { firstName=first; return *this; }
```

p1.print() only prints "Brad". So it is not correct. The question is why?

Now I'm going to do the following. Instead of writing

```
p1.setLastName("Brad").setFirstName("Pitt");
```

as before, I separate this line into two steps:

```
p1.setLastName("Brad");
p1.setFirstName("Pitt")
```

Now p1.print() outputs "Brad Pitt" as I want. As before, I want to know why this works.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Header file:

```
#ifndef personType_H
#define personType_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class personType
{
public:
    personType();
    personType(string first, string last);
    void print() const;
    void setName(string first, string last);
    string getFirstName() const;
    string getLastName() const;
    personType& setLastName(string last);
    personType& setFirstName(string first);

private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
};

#endif // !personType_H
```

cpp file implementing the class:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "personType.h"

personType::personType()
{
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
}

personType::personType(string first, string last)
{
    setName(first, last);
}

void personType::print() const
{
    cout << firstName << " " << lastName << endl;
}

void personType::setName(string first, string last)
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
}

string personType::getFirstName() const
{
    return firstName;
}

string personType::getLastName() const
{
    return lastName;
}

personType& personType::setLastName(string last)
{
    lastName = last;
    return *this;
}

personType& personType::setFirstName(string first)
{
    firstName = first;
    return *this;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    personType p1;
    p1.setLastName("Brad").setFirstName("Pitt");
    p1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is unclear? If you return `personType` type instead of `personType&` - a (temporary) copy, of `personType` is made, upon return of the function, on which the second call of `.setFirstName("Pitt")` is invoked.

Comment: C++ is not the learn-by-trying-and-seeing language.

Comment: On a side note, method chaining is really poor choice here.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't return a reference, then

```
return *this;
```

makes a copy of the object and returns that. When you chain the calls with:

```
p1.setLastName("Brad").setFirstName("Pitt");
```

you're calling `setFirstName()` on the copy, not `p1`. That's why `p1.print()` does show the new first name. It's equivalent to:

```
personType temp = p1.setLastName("Brad");
temp.setFirstName("Pitt");
p1.print();
```

The new first name is in `temp`, not `p1`. To see both changes you would have to do:

```
temp.print();
```

Answer (score 2):

As you did it, your setLastname and setFirstName return a **copy** of the object it is being called to. By returning a reference, you return the object **itself**. So when you return a copy and do

```
person.setFirstname("brad").setSecondname("pitt");
```

this evaluates to:

```
Person p = person.setFirstname("brad); //note: not the original person! a copy of person!
p.setSecondname("pitt");
```

So now you have **two** persons. One with only it's first name set, and one with only the second name set. But, as pointed out in the comments on this answer, the second object, that I referred to as 'p' in my example code, is never stored anywhere and thus immediately destroyed.

Comment: You forgot to mention, that such a copy is temporary, and is destroyed after the execution of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

From ***"The C++ Programming Language"*** by Bjarne Stroustrup (Third Edition). **Section 10.2.7 Self-Reference[class.this]:**

> The state update functions `add_year()`, `add_month()`, and
>   `add_day()` were defined not to return values. For such a set of
>   related update functions, it is often useful to return a reference to
>   the updated object so that the operations can be chained. For example,
>   we would like to write
>
> ```
> void f(Date& d)
> {
>     // ...
>     d.add_day(1).add_month(1).add_year(1);
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> to add a day, a month, and a year to `d`. To do this, each function must be declared to return a reference to a `Date`:
>
> ```
> class Date {
>     // ...
>     Date& add_year(int n); // add n years
>     Date& add_month(int n); // add n months
>     Date& add_day(int n); // add n days
> };
> ```
>
> Each (***nonstatic***) member function knows what object it was invoked for and can  explictly refer to it. For example:
>
> ```
> Date& Date::add_year(int n)
> {
>     if (d == 29 && m == 2 && !leapyear(y + n)) { // beware of February 29
>         d = 1;
>         m = 3;
>     }
>     y += n;
>     return *this;
> }
> ```
>
> The expression `*this` refers to the object for which a member function is invoked. [...]

Answer (score 0):

By returning a reference to yourself you allow method chaining:

When returning by reference, this:

```
p1.setLastName("Brad").setFirstName("Pitt");
```

Is equivalent to:

```
p1.setLastName("Brad");
p1.setFirstName("Pitt");
```

---

When returning by value you create a copy and then call the second method on this copy that is then destroyed because you never assign it to anything.

This:

```
p1.setLastName("Brad").setFirstName("Pitt");
```

Is equivalent to:

```
p1.setLastName("Brad");
Person(p1).setFirstName("Pitt"); // create a temporary Person object that's instantly destroyed on the next line
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the functions that do not return a reference to personType, will first set the calling object's (p1) lastName to the argument and then return a **copy** of the personType object.
    personType setLastName(string last) { lastName=last; return *this; }
    personType setFirstName(string first); { firstName=first; return *this; }

So using these functions as such will not modify p1

```
p1.setLastName("Brad").setFirstName("Pitt");
```

It essentially becomes

```
personType copy = p1.setLastName("Brad")
copy.setFirstName("Pitt");
```

Changing the return type will return a reference to the calling object (p1) which can then be called to modified its contents.

```
personType& setLastName(string last) { lastName=last; return *this; }
personType& setFirstName(string first); { firstName=first; return *this; }
```

So using these functions as such will not modify p1

```
p1.setLastName("Brad").setFirstName("Pitt");
```

It essentially becomes

```
p1 = p1.setLastName("Brad")
p1.setFirstName("Pitt");
```

Notice that I am saying essentially, by this I mean it will behave in a similar manner.